# recursion count of groups

Tags: java, recursion

so  I got a little stuck in the code and if possible help
so the matrix is

```
                    {1,1,0,0,0},
                  {0,1,0,0,1},
                  {1,0,0,1,1},
                  {0,0,0,0,0},
                  {1,0,1,1,0}};
```

so i need to to return how much islands of 1 i have .Here in the example there are 4
I tried to do a double loop and any repetition of it would be added to my count 1 but I got into trouble with an edge case etc.   this is some of my code.
There are probably duplicates because I tried something different every time
help

```
                if(A[i][j]==1&& A[i-1][j]==1&&i>=1 && j>=0 && j<=A[i].length-1 &&i<=A.length-1 ) {
                    A[i][j]=0;
                    count++;
                    printPath1(A, i - 1, j);  }  // up

                if(A[i][j]==1&&A[i][j+1]==1&& i>=0 && j>=0 && j<=A[i].length-1 &&i<=A.length-1 ) {
                    A[i][j]=0;
                    count++;
                    printPath1(A, i, j + 1); }  // right

                if(A[i][j]==1&& A[i][j-1]==1 && i>=0 && j>=1 && j<=A[i].length-1 &&i<=A.length-1 ) {
                    A[i][j]=0;
                    count++;
                    printPath1(A, i, j - 1);}   // left

                if(A[i][j]==1&&A[i-1][j-1]==1&& i>=1 && j>=1 && j<=A[i].length-1 &&i<=A.length-1 ) {
                    A[i][j]=0;
                    count++;
                    printPath1(A, i-1, j - 1); }  

                if(A[i][j]==1&&A[i-1][j+1]==1&& i>=1 && j>=0 && j<=A[i].length-1 &&i<=A.length-1 ) {
                    A[i][j]=0;
                    count++;
                    printPath1(A, i-1, j + 1); }  

                if(A[i][j]==1&&A[i+1][j+1]==1&& i>=0 && j>=0 && j<=A[i].length-1 &&i<=A.length-1 ) {
                    A[i][j]=0;
                    count++;
                    printPath1(A, i+1, j + 1); }  

                if(A[i][j]==1&& A[i+1][j+1]==1&&i>=0 && j>=1 && j<=A[i].length-1 &&i<=A.length-1 ) {
                    A[i][j]=0;
                    count++;
                    printPath1(A, i, j - 1); }   

if(A[i][j]==1&& A[i+1][j]==1&& i>=0 && j>=0 && j<=A[i].length-1 &&i<=A.length-1 ) {
                count++;
                A[i][j]=0;
                printPath1(A, i + 1, j);}   // down
```

Comment: Why have you included word "recursion" into your question?

Comment: ... and define what you mean by "island".

Comment: because i think i need to solve that in recursion ...island is like groups of 1 that Adjacent to each other with no 0

Comment: Adjacent left-right and up-down? Or adjacent diagonally? Or adjacent both?

Comment: diagonally.left.right up down all the Possible directions

Answer (score 2):

Not only do you not need recursion but it is better not to use it.

Keep a list of unvisited cells. Scroll through the matrix looking for unvisited cells, when you find one, you have a new group. Mark all the cells in that group as already visited (so they don't count another group).

A simple way to do it is:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[][] mx = {
                {1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}};
        N2[] cross = new N2[]{new N2(0, -1), new N2(0, 1), new N2(-1, 0), new N2(1, 0)};
        N2[] diagonal = new N2[]{new N2(0, -1), new N2(0, 1), new N2(-1, 0), new N2(1, 0), new N2(-1,-1), new N2(1,-1), new N2(-1,1), new N2(1,1)};
        System.out.printf("%d%n", countGroupsOf(1, mx, cross));
        System.out.printf("%d%n", countGroupsOf(1, mx, diagonal));
        System.out.printf("%d%n", countGroupsOf(0, mx, cross));
        System.out.printf("%d%n", countGroupsOf(0, mx, diagonal));
    }

    private static int countGroupsOf(int value, int[][] mx, N2[] adjacentDeltas) {
        int groups = 0;

        // visited cells with `value` must not be revisited
        Set<N2> visited = new HashSet<>();

        // check all `value` cells
        for (int i = 0; i < mx.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < mx[i].length; j++) {

                N2 p = new N2(i, j);

                if (mx[i][j] == value && !visited.contains(p)) {

                    // new group encountered
                    groups += 1;

                    // visit all `value` cells in this group
                    Queue<N2> expand = new LinkedList<>();
                    expand.add(p);
                    visited.add(p);

                    while (!expand.isEmpty()) {
                        N2 q = expand.poll();
                        // arbitrary adjacency
                        for (N2 d : adjacentDeltas) {
                            N2 r = q.add(d);
                            // adjacent, valid, not visited, `value` cells must be expanded
                            if (r.x >= 0 && r.y >= 0 && r.x < mx.length && r.y < mx[r.x].length && mx[r.x][r.y] == value && !visited.contains(r)) {
                                expand.add(r);
                                visited.add(r);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        return groups;
    }

    static class N2 {
        int x;
        int y;

        N2 add(N2 p) {
            return new N2(x + p.x, y + p.y);
        }
        N2(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return x + 7 * y;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object z) {
            if(!(z instanceof N2))
                return false;
            N2 w = (N2) z;
            return w.x == x && w.y == y;
        }
    }
}
```

With result:

```
5
4
2
1
```

This algorithm works for any adjacency relationship you want to define.

The time and memory complexity is `O(n)` (where `n` is the total cells number).

Comment: Thanks for your time and writing!!
But it's important to note that I need it in the simplest way possible
I mean I haven't yet learned what you wrote ...

Comment: @josejuan: The idea is OK. But the implementation is buggy :) Have you tried to run it? It will come to an endless loop.

Comment: @LiroyLevi: "in the simplest way possible" - This task is not trivial. If you are just starting to learn programming, this is not the right task for you to work on. Find more simple tasks.

Comment: In the meantime, I learned a queue. A stack. A linked list. Some of the things you have not yet known
And that's a question of some of our material

Comment: Then you need to provide such restrictions in your question. This answer is usefull and may even solve the question in the way you have phrased it.

Comment: @mentallurg the output is `5, 4, 2, 1` What problem did you find?

Comment: @josejuan: I wanted to see if it also works for configurations looking like letters "C" or "E". But first I just executed it as is, without any changes. It just hung. After 5 min I interrupted it. I some added tracing, started it again an the same pattern was repeated again and again. I didn't analyzed what the problem is. I suppose may be you placed here some intermediate version that comes to endless loop and may be you have fixed it later but forgotten to place here the working version.

Comment: @mentallurg then, you have downvoted without a proof...; here my own that is working https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1tOj

Comment: My hypothesis is that you have removed the lombok annotations and not implemented either hashCode or equals...

Comment: @josejuan: You are right :) With Lombok it works properly, also in other cases. If you edit your answer, I can vote it up.

Comment: u only need to return how much groups of 1 do u find . and in that example have only 4 and u need to return only the number 4

Comment: Yes @LiroyLevi I'm solving all posibilities, 4 result is for "diagonal are adjacents" and "looking for value 1" but, since you do not explain when two cells are adjacents, I've solved for all cases :)

Comment: @josejuan: I edited your answer. I replaced Lombok with normal code. Edit was accepted. Now I have upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution.

```
public class IslandsMentallurg {

    private static class Cell {

        int col;

        int row;

        Cell(int row, int col) {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + row + "," + col + ")";
        }

    }

    private static int[][] matrix = { //
            { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 }, //
            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 }, //
            { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 }, //
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, //
            { 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 } //
    };

    private static boolean[][] visited;

    private static Cell findNewCell(Cell currentCell) {
        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
            int row = currentCell.row + i;
            if (row < 0 || row >= matrix.length) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                int col = currentCell.col + j;
                if (col < 0 || col >= matrix[row].length) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!visited[row][col] && matrix[row][col] == 1) {
                    return new Cell(row, col);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        visited = new boolean[matrix.length][matrix.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < visited.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < visited[i].length; j++) {
                visited[i][j] = false;
            }
        }

        List<List<Cell>> islands = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < visited.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < visited[i].length; j++) {
                if (!visited[i][j] && matrix[i][j] == 1) {
                    List<Cell> island = new ArrayList<>();
                    islands.add(island);
                    island.add(new Cell(i, j));
                    visited[i][j] = true;
                    int currentCellIndex = 0;
                    do {
                        Cell currentCell = island.get(currentCellIndex);
                        Cell newCell = findNewCell(currentCell);
                        if (newCell != null) {
                            island.add(newCell);
                            visited[newCell.row][newCell.col] = true;
                            currentCellIndex = island.size() - 1;
                            continue;
                        }
                        currentCellIndex--;
                    } while (currentCellIndex >= 0);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("Number of 1-islands:   %d\n", islands.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < islands.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("Island %d:   ", i + 1);
            List<Cell> island = islands.get(i);
            for (Cell cell : island) {
                System.out.printf("%s, ", cell);
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i try to run it on eclipse and its tell me that have some problems with that code

Comment: What problems exactly?